# PHP script not recognising my mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I am new to php and mysql and I have began coding a simple social media network. So I am currently working on my login.php page which seem to have no errors, but it is not working as it should and I am assuming it is because the query is not being recognised as a statement. i.e "password" should not be highlighted as a key word but it is a field in the database. I am also aware that I have not considered injection. When I run this in the browser there are no errors but it returns "User not registered" even when a user is in the database. Any insight would be great thanks!

Here is my code:

```
<?php
include('classes/DB.php');
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    if (DB::query('SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=:username', 
      array(':username'=>$username))) {
            if (password_verify($password, DB::query("SELECT password FROM 
      users WHERE username=:username", array(':username'=>$username))[0] 
      ['password'])) {
                    echo 'Logged in!';
            } else {
                    echo 'Incorrect Password!';
            }
    } else {
            echo 'User not registered!';
    }
}
```

Here is my DB.php class:

```
 <?php
  class DB {
    private static function connect() {
            $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=SocialNetwork;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            return $pdo;
    }
    public static function query($query, $params = array()) {
            $statement = self::connect()->prepare($query);
            $statement->execute($params);
            if (explode(' ', $query)[0] == 'SELECT') {
            $data = $statement->fetchAll();
            return $data;
            }
    }
 }
```

Comment: _Any insight would be great..._ For that we would need to look at the definition of `DB::query()`

Comment: How are the passwords stored in the database created? They must be created with `password_hash()`

Comment: We need your `DB` class, we can't really help you without it.

Comment: @rpm192 I have added my db.php class

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php
include('classes/DB.php');
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    if (DB::query('SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=:username', 
      array('username'=>$username))) {
            if (password_verify($password, DB::query("SELECT password FROM 
      users WHERE username=:username", array('username'=>$username))[0] 
      ['password'])) {
                    echo 'Logged in!';
            } else {
                    echo 'Incorrect Password!';
            }
    } else {
            echo 'User not registered!';
    }
}
```

Comment: It gives me the same thing. "User not registered" for a registered user

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.
A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @codeAspire you need to share more code, especially `classes/DB.php` and the code used to generate passwords. Also the login form's HTML code would be good, maybe you have a simple typo in the form field's name or something. Anyway your question is INCOMPLETE!

Comment: @TheCoprolal I have added the DB.php class